# SQL - Compare several values based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql

After multiple attempts, I'm looking for your advices on the below issue.

I have a table like:

| Serial_num | Status_Comp1 | Status_Comp2 | Status_Comp3 | Risk_Comp1 | Risk_Company2 | Risk_Comp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001248674554 | Active | Inactive | Active | 4 | 5 | 4 |
| 001248674598 | Inactive | Active | Active | 3 | 3 | 4 |

Please take into account that I have 5 different `Risk_Comp` and `Status_Comp` columns. I just did not have enough space to display them all here.

The Risk_Comp columns can have the below possible values :

- null
- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7

I would like to compare the values within the:

- Risk_Comp1
- Risk_Comp2
- Risk_Comp3
- Risk_Comp4
- Risk_Comp5

Only where `Status_Comp = 'Active'`.

Please take into account that I have 5 different `Risk_Comp` and `Status_Comp` columns.

My aim is to have a column which compare the Risk_Comp columns where Status_Comp = 'Active'

I already tried several solutions including MODULO but it won't work properly.

I found a solution with `CASE` and then filtering after an Excel export. But the SQL code is very long and the solution is not very efficient.

Does anyone has an advice regarding how to compare multiple values based on several conditions ?

Many thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: What does it mean to "compare the values within"?

Comment: @GSerg : It means compare the values in the columns Risk_Comp1, Risk_Comp2, Risk_Comp3, Risk_Comp4, Risk_Comp5

Comment: What does it mean to compare values in five columns? What is the result of such comparison? Is there even one result? Or five results, one for each column? Or 10 results, one for each possible pair?

Comment: Does your database have unpivot operator? If  even it does not, you can simulate its behavior by unioning 5 subqueris (for every Risk_Comp column, with where clause for corresponding Status_Comp) and grouping them afterwards. Is it efficient or not, this we can't know.

Comment: GSerg : I would like to know if the Risk_Comp columns have all the same values or not - only for active ones. So the comparing column should state something like "OK" if they all have the same value, or "MISTAKE' if it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

use this simple approach :

```
      SELECT
      serial_num,
      Risk_Comp1,
      Risk_Comp2,
      Risk_Comp3, 
... Other similar cols 
     <risk comp compare column case statement logic awaited>
      Status_Comp1,
      Status_Comp2,
      Status_Comp3
... other similar cols 
    FROM
      my_table
    WHERE
      Status_Comp =  'Active'
```

The `WHERE` clause in the above code is used to filter the rows where the `Status_Comp` column is equal to '`Active`'.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @user1874594. 

In several rows, there are Status_Comp1 and Status_Comp2 'Active' and Status_Comp3 'Inacctive' and I need to compare the values of Risk_Comp1 and Risk_Comp2 but not Risk_Comp3 has it is 'Inactive'.

Not sure if you see what I mean...

Comment: hi can you update the question and add more detail so it clarifies what you are looking for and I will take a look after I wake up in the morning

Comment: Hi, I just upadted the question. Could you please let me know if it is easier to understand on your side ?
Thanks

Comment: >> *My aim is to have a column which compare the Risk_Comp columns where Status_Comp = 'Active'  .What should be the logic of this column ? how should it look .  If all you want to do is compare then take a look at above modified as\